# oracle export and import datapump

Tags: oracle11g, datapump

I have a quick question on oracle datapump. I have a small oracle database 11gR2 which contains different schemas (more than 8).I want to move this database to a new server and i am trying to use impdp/expdp method. I did a full export of the database under system user. THe new server also runs 11gR2.
Now if create a new database with same tablespaces on the new server, can i use a full import. Is this the recommended way to do it?
I know i can do it schema wise, but however it would require me creating the roles, and other supporting objects first and also identifying which schemas actually have objects on them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such a thing as a "recommended" way to do it.  You might as well ask what's the "recommended" data to put in an Oracle database.  It kind of depends what your needs are.

The only problem that I've had with using a "full" import/export in the past, is that the export then also includes SYSTEM (and other default Oracle schemas) which you don't really want overwriting your new database.  (Actually, this used to cause me some problems with the old imp/exp command -- but theoretically it would be the same problem with Data Pump).

Fortunately, Data Pump allows you to exclude certain objects from your export.  When I do full exports, I tend to exclude all the schemas that are already created in the new database, at db-creation time.  Include the following in your parameter file:

`EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:" IN ('SYS','SYSTEM','WMSYS','OUTLN','MGMT_VIEW','XDB','ANONYMOUS','SYSMAN','ORDSYS','ORDSYS','ORDPLUGINS','SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','MDSYS','EXFSYS','DBSNMP','DMSYS','CTXSYS','DIP','TSMSYS','ORACLE_OCM')"`